# How to show and hide div in combobox using PHP Jquery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a combo box with fixed list (not from database) and I want to show the correspond div (with other dynamic combo box and input form) when user choose one of the list from the combo box, how it can be done using PHP jQuery Ajax?

I try to use the script below to show the div, but it always show when the combo box changed on every item.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#activity").change(function(){
        var activity = $("#activity").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "proses_host.php",
            data: "activity=" + activity,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#host1").fadeOut(200);
            }
        });
      });
   });
   </script>
```

Comment: Just with this code, it is difficult to tell but try to put breakpoints to see what is wrong like check if data is being passed, check value of activity,  and on success, alert and see what are you getting as response

Comment: "other dynamic combo box" from database ?

Comment: I mean, if I select item1 from combobox, it show div1, and if I select item2, it show div2.. etc.